# gridview sorting based on a specific column values

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I have a gridview with following columns.

[image]

I want to sort gridview based on status. Red status should come first (up) then green status.

Please suggest how can I do?

This is my code :

```
Using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT Instance,ServerName,IPFQDN,Status from server_interspc")) 
{ 
    using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) 
        {
            sda.Fill(dt); 
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of affectation of datatsource to your GridView ?

Comment: using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT Instance,ServerName,IPFQDN,Status from server_interspc"))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                        GridView1.DataBind();
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: Is Status an actual string "Red" or "Green"? If so that is a bad habit to get into.  Don't duplicate meaning,  A "Status code" is not the same as a "Status Description".  A status code is sortable by some defined priority level.  Sorting strings as a status code or using strings that just happen to sort in the proper priority order is bad form.

Comment: And to take it one step further.  If it isn't already, I would create a Status table that has 3 fields: `SortPriority`,`StatusCode`,`StatusDescription`.  This way you can avoid duplication of meaning again by separating Priority from the actual Code.  Granted this might be overkill for an up/down status but I hope you can see the benefits

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to change you code to :

```
   sda.Fill(dt);   
   DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
   //Sorting datatable as you like before set it as datasource of your gridView
   dv.Sort = "Status desc";  // Or      dv.Sort = "Status asc";
   DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();
   GridView1.DataSource = sortedDT;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query to

```
SELECT Instance,ServerName,IPFQDN,Status from server_interspc GROUP BY Status ORDER BY Status desc
```